# Symfony query database using foreign key

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 5 and have a question about retrieving from the database using a foreign key.

I have a User entity and an AdditionalInfo entity, which has a 1:1 relationship with User, although actually not all users will have AdditionalInfo. On the AdditionalInfo entity there is a user field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="AddInfo", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;
```

In the database it has stored this as
In my controller I have the current user and am trying to access the AdditionalInfo entry for this user by:

```
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();
    
    $aI= new AdditionalInfo();
    
    $aI= $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(AdditionalInfo::class)
    ->findOneBy(['user' => '$userId']);
```

This gets the correct user ID but is returning null. It's also null if I try ->findOneBy(['user' => '$user'])

I would be very grateful for any suggestions. I'm wondering if I need to start trying to alter the repository...

Comment: can you please provide the user side of the relationship?

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=PtNarrative::class, mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $addInfo;

Comment: Don't quote `$userId`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way of doing this:

```
$aI= $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository(AdditionalInfo::class)
->findOneByUser($user);
```

I didn't realise the findOneByUser method had been automatically created, that's really helpful.